# rails 4 flash session discarded after redirecting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flash

As far as I know the flash should be store in session,

I've already clear browser cache, and restart rails server.

The flash just couldn't work. even I use `flash.keep` it didn't work at all.

Where did I missing ?

And I found in the root_path method, I inspected the session variables

The flash are discarded, I've no idea about that.

## Debug console

```
[1] pry(#<WelcomeController>)> session
{
    "_csrf_token" => "y+QzSyv23dzSWEcf+9D+i49zkC748j++gwFVjafN7A0=",
          "flash" => {
        "discard" => [
            [0] "alert",
            [1] "error"
        ],
        "flashes" => {
            "alert" => "尚未有該航線資訊，請選擇不同出發地與目的地或者日期",
            "error" => "Insufficient rights!"
        }
    }
}
```

## initailize/session_store.rb

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_websites_session'
```

## flash.html.haml

```
- flash.each do |name, msg|
  = content_tag :div, msg.html_safe, class: "panel-title panel-info"
```

## controller.rb

```
  flash[:alert] = t('no_available_routes')
  redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Successfully checked in"
```

## development.rb

```
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store
  config.cache_store = :dalli_store, ENV['MEMCACHE_DB'], { :pool_size => 10 ,compress: true }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an ugly workaround for my question,

I can still get the flash data in session on the view,

But I still want to know how can I use the normal `flash` variable in my case

Thanks

```
- if session["flash"]
  -  session["flash"]["flashes"].each do |name, msg|
    - if 'alert' == name
      = content_tag :div, msg.html_safe, class: "panel-warning"
    - else
      = content_tag :div, msg.html_safe, class: "panel-info"
```